# F# Dividing Functions Error: Expecting a type supporting the operator '/' but given a function type

Tags: function, f#

I'm not an F# programmer. I'm modifying an existing library.

I'm trying and slowly picking it up.

What I'm trying to do is divide two functions.

I can see it done through the rest of the library so I know it's possible however when i try and divide i get the error

"Expecting a type supporting the operator '/' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function"

This is where the errors occurring

```
let sharpeRatio2 pfRets bmkRets x  =
    let top pfRets bmkRets = excessReturns2 pfRets bmkRets
    let bottom pfRets x = volatilty pfRets false x
    let result = top / bottom
    result
```

The sub functions called i think are all good, with the only question mark on the volatility one which i created it should multiply the std result by sqrt(12)

Top (Returns)

```
let excessReturns2 (pfRets: seq<float>) bmkRets =
    Seq.zip pfRets bmkRets |> Seq.map activeReturn
    |> Seq.zip

let inline activeReturn (ret, bmkRet) = ret - bmkRet
```

Bottom (Volatility)

```
    let var xs nmethod = 
    match Seq.fold (fun (i, s, sumsq) x -> i + 1, s + x, sumsq + x * x) (0, 0., 0.) xs with
    | 0, _, _ -> 0.
    | 1, _, _ when not nmethod -> 0.
    | n, xsum, xsumsq ->
        // denominator is (n-1) or n
        let d = if nmethod then float n else float n - 1.
        (xsumsq - xsum * xsum / float n) / d

    let std xs nmethod = sqrt (var xs nmethod)

    let volatilty xs nmethod x = (std xs nmethod) * sqrt (x)
```

Any thoughts welcome please

Thanks gws

Comment: this is where the type inference makes it a bit difficult to see what's going on. Can you show the type signature of both the `top` and `bottom` functions? You can just copy it from the REPL if necessary.

Comment: My guess is that maybe you didn't supply all the arguments to your function so top or bottom is not a number (yet).

Comment: I'm sorry I'll have to work out  what you mean. I believe     TOP is seq<float>->seq<float>->seq<'d>->seq<float*'d>  and    bottom <seq<float> -> float -> float

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, and you can see that you are trying to divide a list of numbers with one number. Which of course you cannot do. Please see my answer below. If you want a series of sharpe ratios for each day or month return you can use Seq.map.

Comment: You also mispelt "volatility" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
open System
let rnd = Random()
rnd.NextDouble()

let ret1 = List.init 100 (fun _ -> rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5)
let ret2 = List.init 100 (fun _ -> rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5)

let inline activeReturn (ret, bmkRet) = ret - bmkRet
let excessReturns2 (pfRets: seq<float>) bmkRets =
    Seq.zip pfRets bmkRets |> Seq.map activeReturn |> Seq.sum

let var xs nmethod = 
    match Seq.fold (fun (i, s, sumsq) x -> i + 1, s + x, sumsq + x * x) (0, 0., 0.) xs with
    | 0, _, _ -> 0.
    | 1, _, _ when not nmethod -> 0.
    | n, xsum, xsumsq ->
        // denominator is (n-1) or n
        let d = if nmethod then float n else float n - 1.
        (xsumsq - xsum * xsum / float n) / d

let std xs nmethod = sqrt (var xs nmethod)
let volatilty xs nmethod x = (std xs nmethod) * sqrt (x)


let sharpeRatio2 pfRets bmkRets x  =
    let top = excessReturns2 pfRets bmkRets
    let bottom  = volatilty pfRets false x
    let result = top / bottom
    result

sharpeRatio2 ret1 ret2 12.
```

Some comments:

1. Try defining and posting the functions in order as the F# compiler goes left to right and top to bottom. So `activeReturn` has to come before `excessreturn` and the `top` and `bottom` functions before the `sharperatio`.
2. There is an error in your `excessReturns2` function, at the very end you have a `Seq.zip` you are piping into. I assume that is actually either a `Seq.sum` or `Seq.average` (you want the total active return for the period or an average daily/monthly active return). Either you want one number.
3. This line (and also the next one): `excessReturns2 pfRets bmkRets`: here excessReturns2 is a function that takes two arguments the portfolio and the benchmark return. This function will return one number, which is top, so you can just say `let top = excessReturns2 pfRets bmkRets`, ditto for bottom.
4. You are better off, using [Mathdotnet](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/), and calling the StandardDeviation functions from there. No need to define your own.

Let me know if you have any questions.

**On Mathdotnet**

This is a great library and if you can have a dependency on it you should be able to just say:

```
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.Statistics

Statistics.StandardDeviation ret1
```

You also use the portfolio return standard deviation when dividing the active return. You should ideally use the active return's standard deviation if you need to look at the Information Ratio.

Comment: Thank you for stepping me through the solution, what was wrong, how to solve it and alternatives. Would you believe i had seq.sum to calc excess returns and some how when debugging i've changed it to .zip by accident an wasn't even looking at this as the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
let top pfRets bmkRets = excessReturns2 pfRets bmkRets
```

you are *not* calculating the value of `top` based on the passed-in variables `pfRets2` and `bmkRets`. Instead, you are only defining a *function*, `top`, that *happens* to use the same names for its arguments as `shapeRatio2` - but those arguments are left unspecified.

That is, both function take arguments called `pfRets` and `bmkRets`, but calling `excessReturns2` does *not* automatically also call `top` with those same parameters; it only records its definition.

The same, obviously, applies to `bottom`.

Since you want `top` and `bottom` to be *values*, you need to define them *without* arguments (that's the simplest difference between values and functions: the latter take arguments, the former do not):

```
let sharpeRatio2 pfRets bmkRets x  =
    let top = excessReturns2 pfRets bmkRets
    let bottom = volatilty pfRets false x
    let result = top / bottom
    result
```